# Game pieces smaller than a bingo chip

Tags: custom-game-pieces

I'm designing a board game and am looking to purchase a quantity of small tokens to serve as markers.  Ideally, they would be wooden, pre-painted (I'm not picky about color as long as there are a few different colors), and very small.  I need about 100, in three different colors.

The best I can find online are bingo chips, which are usually .75" to 1" and too large.  Does anyone know what I can search for to find game pieces in the quarter to half inch size?  It doesn't matter what shape, as long as they shapes aren't known objects, like unicorns or sailboats or something.  Cubes, discs, etc are all fine.

What are tokens of this size commonly called, so I can search for them on my own?

Comment: While this is a question about designing a game it does appear to be more of a shopping question as you are looking for someone to find an item online.

Comment: Not asking for someone to find an item online rather what search term to use.

Comment: I am just stating what it appears like to me

Comment: I do a lot of of game design and prototyping. If you have other games in your collection that have the token/parts you want just use them for a prototype.  Saves buying anything.

Comment: Yes, that, @StartPlayer and also thrift stores for old used games on the cheap with reusable boards and dice and tokens!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two types of wooden markers you might be interested in:

- 15mm disks (for example, [these on MeepleSource](https://www.meeplesource.com/products.php?cat=27))

  [image: Wooden disks]
- Wooden cubes, which frequently come in 8mm, 10mm or 12mm (for example, [these on MeepleSource](https://www.meeplesource.com/products.php?cat=16))

  [image: Wooden cubes]

This is not an ad for MeepleSource; you can buy these types of parts from a number of online sources.